# VHDL initialize signed of variable length to maximum value

Tags: vhdl

I've got the following function that returns the value variable when it can be represented with the length given as a parameter. If value is out of limits, it should return the maximum possible value or the maximum negative value depending on the sign of value.

```
function truncate (
  value   : in signed;
  length  : in integer)
  return signed is
constant max_positive_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := ((length-1) => '0', others => '1');
constant max_negative_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := ((length-1) => '1', others => '0');
variable return_value        : signed(length-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
  if (value >= max_positive_value) then
    return_value := max_positive_value;
  elsif (value <= max_negative_value) then
    return_value := max_negative_value;
  else
    return_value := resize(value, length);
  end if;
  return return_value;
end;
```

The problem is the initialization of the `max_positive_value` and `max_negative_value`. GHDL complains about `not static choice exclude others choice`.
How can I initialize the limit values if the length is variable?
I'm using VHDL 93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do it that Modelsim accepts without a warning but length needs to be smaller than 32:

```
    constant max_positive_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := to_signed(2**(length-1)-1, length);
    constant max_negative_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := to_signed(-2**(length-1), length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, since your odd-man-out is on the left, you can do this:

```
constant max_positive_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := ('0', others => '1');
constant max_negative_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := ('1', others => '0');
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/64S7

The LRM says

> Apart from a final element association with the single choice others,
>   the rest (if any) of the element associations of an array aggregate
>   shall be either all positional or all named. A named association of an
>   array aggregate is allowed to have a choice that is not locally
>   static, or likewise a choice that is a null range, only if the
>   aggregate includes a single element association and this element
>   association has a single choice. An others choice is locally static if
>   the applicable index constraint is locally static.

which is as clear as mud.

Comment: This fixed the error in GHDL but modelsim vcom still shows a warning `Non-locally static OTHERS choice is allowed only if it is the only choice of the only association.`

Comment: Before posting my answer, I tried it on two other simulators and it just so happens that I found two that were both happy. I've just tried another and it has the same opinion as Modelsim. I must be down to the startling clarity of the LRM.

Comment: The EDA playground code the function call parameter for length is a locally static expression (`V5 := truncate(V, 5);`). The constant declarations in the function declarative part are elaborated at run time following elaboration of the parameter list. Note that this is a Modelsim warning unless using -pendanticerrors (see verror for the particular not-provided message number). -IEEE Std 10761993 7.3.3 Function calls "Evaluation of a function call includes evaluation of the actual parameter expressions specified in the call...".

Comment: 2.1 Subprogram declarations, 2.1.1 Formal parameters, 2.1.1.1 Constant and variable parameters, "For a nonforeign subprogram having a parameter of a scalar type or an access type, the parameter is passed by copy."  How that copying is done isn't defined while 7.3.3 says the actual parameter expression is evaluated.

Comment: s/others/(length-2 downto 0)/ but Katu's answer is less hacky

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do it is to declare a constant locally to work around the good old "not locally static" VHDL issues:

```
constant C_LEN : integer := length
constant max_negative_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := ((C_LEN-1) => '1', others => '0');
```

Comment: This doesn't avoid the warning message compiling with Quartus vcom

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be;

```
constant max_positive_value : signed(length-1 downto 0) := (others => '1') SRL 1;
constant max_negative_value : signed(length-1 downto 0) := NOT max_signed;
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use concatenate:

```vhdl
constant max_positive_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := '0' & (length-2 downto 0 => '1');
constant max_negative_value  : signed(length-1 downto 0) := '1' & (length-2 downto 0 => '0');
```

I also like Katu's solution for values that are representable in type integer.   Slightly concerned about the calculation of 2**(length-1)-1 when length is 32.  Since length is integer, if the whole expression then integer, the 2**(Length-1) will overflow before subtracting 1.   OTOH 2**31-1 would be calculated as universal integer and would be fine.